# Javascript to open new window

Tags: javascript

I'd like to have a link open in a new pop-up browser window.  In non-WordPress with JavaScript I would do it some like this (but I would add some underlink/color to make it look like a link).

```
<span 
onClick="myRef = window.open('/Paid_Videos/AudioGenerator01.html','mywin',
'left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0');
myRef.focus()">My Video Blah Blah Blah</span>
```

In WordPress, this shows up on my page like this:

```
onClick="myRef = window.open('/Paid_Videos/AudioGenerator01.html','mywin',
'left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0');
myRef.focus()">My Video Blah Blah Blah
```

What can I do to make it work in WordPress?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line breaks from your input. `wpautop()` will insert a `<br />` otherwise.